# Show Multiple Selection Outputs in Gallery with ThisItem

Tags: powerapps

I have a field that shows task owner(s) and am trying to represent these within my Gallery. It works when I only have one task owner (Rob) but when I have two (Rob & Eric) then I can't figure out how to show it. Any ideas?

Normal process: ThisItem.Owner

Process with dropdown: ThisItem.Owner.Value

Process with multi-select: ???

Expected output:
Rob, Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controls will give you back a table of selected values, and then you want to use the [Concat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-concatenate) function to convert a table column into a string.

Say you control is a list box. You can collect the values

```
Concat(ListBox1.SelectedItems, Value &  ";")
```

If it's a gallery, it will be like:

```
Concat(Gallery2.AllItems, ThisRecord.Subtitle2.Text & ";")
```

There's also more discussion of this on the powerusers forum at: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Concatenating-Column-Values-to-String/td-p/107682